# Inserting random data to tables with foreign keys of a MySQL database via python

Tags: python, mysql, insert, foreign-keys

I have inserted data into some of the tables of the db which don't have foreign keys and now I would like to insert data to the rest of them.
I have 50 ShowNames and 50 theaters in two lists. Each theater has an auto increment HallID. I don't care how random are the lists, so I used a for loop with i corresponding to one ShowName and one HallID. I also have created a two dimensional list actDateTime where each show has a list of datetimes.
I want to insert the above data to a table with these data types:
(PK, AI) ActID int(4)
(FK) ShowName varchar(255)
(FK) HallID int(3)
ActStartTime datetime

Here is my code:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
# defining the Query
query = "INSERT INTO act (ShowName, HallID, ActStartTime) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"


values = []  
# executing the query with values  
for i in range(0, 50):  
    # storing values in a variable  
    lst = []  
    lst.append("select ShowName from shows where ShowName=%s" % showTitles[i])  
    lst.append("select HallID from hall where HallID=%d" % i)  
    for j in range(0, len(actDateTime[i])):  
        lst2 = lst  
        lst2.append(actDateTime[i][j])  
        lst2 = tuple(lst2)  
        values.append(lst2)  

cursor.executemany(query, values)  


# to make final output we have to run the 'commit()' method of the database object  
db.commit()
```

The error I got:
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Don't I return 3 values as I am supposed to do?

I tried to insert a single line of data with MySQL Workbench:

`INSERT INTO act (ShowName, HallID, ActStartTime) VALUES ("SELECT ShowName from shows where ShowName=A Flock Of Hopeful Lions", "select HallID from hall where HallID=1", "2020-10-3 12:45:00")`

Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'select HallID from hall where HallID=1' for column 'HallID' at row 1

HALL table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFPBb.jpg
SHOWS table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yxJl.jpg

Comment: you're appending the actual query to a list and then using the query as a parameter in the actual query, I think what you want is to store the outputs of those queries

Comment: @aws_apprentice cursor.executemany takes as a parameter "query" and "values". "query" is the actual query and for "values" I calculate them inside the for loop. lst is a list where I store showName and HallID and I find them from the corresponding foreign keys.lst2 is a list to append actDateTimes, which is a two dimension list, back to lst. I don't get exactly what you mean. Could you be more specific please?

Comment: I don’t think you understand, your select queries are simply strings and you are appending them to the list and then trying to insert them as a values in the act table. this is also evident by the query you are trying to run in workbench.

Comment: @aws_apprentice This is the right format for MySQL: INSERT INTO act (ShowName, HallID, ActStartTime)  VALUES ((SELECT ShowName from shows where ShowName="A Flock Of Hopeful Lions") ,(SELECT HallID from hall where HallID=1),  "2020-10-3 12:45:00")
So those quotes on SELECTS are causing the problem. I tried adding parentheses inside those quotes, but that's not it. Here is values[0]=('(select ShowName from shows where ShowName=A Flock Of Hopeful Lions)', '(select HallID from hall where HallID=0)', datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 29, 18, 14))
What I am supposed to do?

Comment: I tried adding triple quotes but didn't help either.

Comment: you need to evaluate those query strings within the database, you’re just inserting the query as a string not the actual result of that query. i’m sorry but I can’t help you further because it seems you do not understand. best of luck.